# OSX - Compile to WebAssembly with llc "llc: : error: unable to get target for 'wasm32', see --version and --triple."

Tags: c, clang, llvm, webassembly, llc

I'm running on **OSX** and trying to compile following c code to webAssembly:

```
void test(){
    //do stuff
}
```

I've looked at [this example](https://gist.github.com/yurydelendik/4eeff8248aeb14ce763e) and tried running the following commands:

```
clang -emit-llvm --target=wasm32 -Oz test.c -c -o test.bc
llc -asm-verbose=false -o test.s test.bc
```

First command works fine and clang generates the .bc file, but when I try to run the second command I get:`llc: : error: unable to get target for 'wasm32', see --version and --triple.`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As that page says, it's out of date. Try `--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your version of llvm was not compiled with support for the WebAssembly backend.  This backend is still experimental so you need to enable it at cmake time with: 
`-DLLVM_EXPERIMENTAL_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=WebAssembly`